# Windows 7 Natively on Mac OS X Bootcamp, Airport Wifi Unable To Connect

Tags: windows-7, macbook, boot-camp

I am using a brand new MacBook Pro.
I am running a copy of Windows 7 natively via bootcamp (No use of Virtual Machine Software at all). However the only way I can get Windows to connect to the internet is via Ethernet, as opposed to the Macs Airport card picking up the wireless. It just refuses to connect, and gives me a limited access status.

Any ideas!?

I've run Windows XP natively via bootcamp and I had a few issues with the network constantly dropping out, however I blamed that on the drivers and the general crumminess of XP....

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All kinds of fixes here: [Apple - Support - Discussions - Bluetooth, Networking, Airport and Wi-Fi](http://discussions.apple.com/forum.jspa?forumID=1242)

Answer (score 0):

Bootcamp now supports Windows 7. Upgrade to the latest version and it will support windows 7

Answer (score 0):

There is full compatability with Windows 7 and Mac OS X, it has been compatible for a long time. Try disabling your network adapter and re-enabling it in the adapter settings. `Network and Sharing Center` > `Change Adapter Settings` (At the Sidebar)

You can also try reinstalling the latest bootcamp drivers: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1371

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned on apple website, windows 7 is still not fully supported by bootcamp for the moment. When the support will come (no date announced), be sure that drivers for macbook pro will be windows 7 compatible.